# Desabilitar movimento do mapa com o mouse

Tags: javascript, c#, mapas

Tenho uma pagina com um mapa do mapLink, gostaria de desabilitar a opção de movimentar (arrastar) o mapa com o mouse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**UPDATE**

Entrei em contato com o suporte do mapLink, eles me passaram a função `disableDragging()`, questionei eles sobre a documentação, e me passaram que estão atualizando a mesma, que essa função não esta disponível ainda.

Exemplo:

```
var map = new MMap2(divIdMap);
map.disableDragging();
```

Comment: Cara, a API da Maplink é bem ruim, mas dê uma olhada para ver se encontra o que está procurando: [Maplink API JS](http://dev.maplink.com.br/javascript-api/funcionalidades/). Caso não consiga, entre em contato com o suporte deles.

Comment: Estou olhando aqui a documentação a um tempo, já consegui desabilitar o zoom, obrigado pela dica.